# Visual Studio isn't deploying new files to IIS Express

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I've create a new project in Visual Studio 2013. It is a `HTML Application with TypeScript` project. When I deploy it (Ctrl-F5, or F5), I do not see changes that I've made to my html/css/ts files. How do I get VS to redeploy the site to IIS Express?

I should add that this is very non-deterministic.

I should add that this only seems to be a problem with IE, not with Chrome.

Comment: If it is a problem in one web browser and not another, then you should suspect the web browser. Have you tried Ctrl+F5 in IE to force a reload of the page ?

Comment: I started seeing it in Chrome as well now. This is all non deterministic, so I'll try Ctrl-F5 from the browser next time and let you know.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I think you're right. Ctrl+F5 got this to work. Feel free to put it as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you notice different behaviour between browsers, you should suspect the web browser.

You can force a reload of the page in Internet Explorer with Ctrl+F5.

You may also want to set the HTTP expires header by using a [clientCache](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) entry in the web.config file:

> "The  element of the  element specifies cache-related HTTP headers that IIS 7 and later sends to Web clients, which control how Web clients and proxy servers will cache the content that IIS 7 and later returns.
>
> For example, the httpExpires attribute specifies a date and time that the content should expire, and IIS 7 and later will add an HTTP "Expires" header to the response. The value for the httpExpires attribute must be a fully-formatted date and time that follows the specification in RFC 1123. For example: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 12:00:00 GMT"

...but do remember to set it appropriately for the actual web site when you deploy it "for real". Or you might decide that using `cacheControlMaxAge` is more suitable.